Nexus3 endless cycling trying to update CLM within a DMZ
I'm trying to start a fresh instance of Sonatype Nexus in a Linux environment within a DMZ - so I have limited outgoing http calls, in this case the firewal stops this.
The problem I'm having is that it will not complete start up but is endlessly cycling on retrying access to 
  ... https://clm.sonatype.com:443: Connection reset ...
In this state, the user interface will never come up.
I don't need these options - I don't plan on using CLM right now anyway.
Unfortunately all the help (much of it automated) begins directs me to shut it off with the user interface.
 I do not want to make an exception to our DMZ, but cannot find a way to configure it to not try to setup CLM.

Other details - version is nexus-3.70.3-01 as I'm preparing to migrate from the OrientDB to H2

My workaround: I copied the blobs and db directories from my older instance to the fresh instance before starting it. This did let me start up the instance and I'm proceeding from there. 
I don't consider this a particularly good answer because it doesn't actually answer what I originally asked. Nevertheless it might help someone (including "future me") when they actually need to have a fresh install of that particular version.  It might be peculiar to this release. To be seen. Best!
